# Prove that $|\sin(z)|\geq|\sin(x)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $|\sin(z)|\geq|\sin(x)|$
**My attempt:**
We know by definition:

> $$\begin{align}\sin(z)&=\frac{\exp(iz)-\exp(-iz)}{2}=\frac{\exp(-y)\exp(ix)-\exp(y)\exp(-iy)}{2}\\&=\frac{\exp(-y)(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))-\exp(y)(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))}{2}\\&=\frac{(\exp(-y)-\exp(y))(\cos(x)-i\sin(y))}{2}\end{align}$$

Then $|\sin(z)|=\dfrac{\exp(-y)-\exp(y)}{2}$.

Moreover using the same argument we have that, $|\sin(x)|=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: You forgot to divide by $i$. Then compute the real part of $\sin z$.

Answer (score 2):

You're better off using trig identities and hyperbolic functions, starting with the angle addition formula for the sine function:

$$\begin{align}
\sin(z)=\sin(x+iy)
&=\sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy)\\
&=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)
\end{align}$$

Thus, using the identities $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$ and $\cosh^2(y)-\sinh^2(y)=1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
|\sin(z)|^2
&=\sin^2(x)\cosh^2(y)+\cos^2(x)\sinh^2(y)\\
&=\sin^2(x)(\cosh^2(y)-\sinh^2(y))+\sinh^2(y)\\
&=\sin^2(x)+\sinh^2(y)\\
&\ge\sin^2(x)
\end{align}$$

Taking square roots how gives $|\sin(z)|\ge|\sin(x)|$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake reexpressing $\sin z$. Instead,

$$\sin z =\frac{e^{i(x+iy)}-e^{-i(x+iy)}}{2i}$$
$$=\frac{e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)-e^{y}(\cos x-i\sin x)}{2i}$$
$$=\frac{(e^{-y}-e^{y})\cos x+i(e^{-y}+e^{y})\sin x}{2i}$$
$$=i\sinh y \cos x+\cosh y \sin x$$

Then, with $\cosh y \ge1$,

$$ |\sin z|^2=\sinh^2 y\> \cos^2 x + \cosh^2 y\> \sin^2 x 
\ge\cosh^2 y\> \sin^2 x \ge \sin^2 x$$

Thus,

$$ |\sin z| \ge |\sin x|$$

Comment: $|\sin z|^2=\sinh^2 y\> \cos^2 x + \cosh^2 y\> \sin^2 x$ why this happen?

Comment: @Bvss12 - It is derived from $|\sin z|^2 = ( i\sinh y \cos x+\cosh y \sin x)(-i\sinh y \cos x+\cosh y \sin x)$.

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for your great answer

Comment: @Bvss12 - you're welcome